# Web Scraping a Youtube channel to get the list of videos and other details

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** the list of all the uploaded videos of [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/user/aandawesome/videos) website. I am using `Beautifulsoap` to get the following details: 
(1) Title 
(2) Views 
(2) Upload date

I did some inspection and found out that the `div id="details" class="style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer` can be used to get the details. This is my Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

my_url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/aandawesome/videos"

r = requests.get(my_url)
page = r.text
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')
res=soup.find_all("div",{
    "id": "dismissable",
    "class": ["style-scope", "ytd-grid-video-renderer"]
})

print(res)
```

But I am not able to access that div. The output is empty. What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: It would be better to use youtube's API to find this information.

Comment: What is happening to not find the div is because it loads by Javascript, I advise you to use Selenium, which will bring better results.

Comment: Does it mean that youtube code is designed in a way that we can not scrap video details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below code will help you.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',-1)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

my_url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/aandawesome/videos"

r = requests.get(my_url)
page = (r.text)
soup=bs(page,'html.parser')

d = []
for match in soup.find_all('div',class_="yt-lockup-content"):
    view = match.find('ul',class_="yt-lockup-meta-info")
    d.append(
        {
            'Title': match.a.text,
            'View': view.text.split("views")[0],
            'Upload date':view.text.split("views")[1]
        }
    )

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This code works perfectly. This shows that the code that we see in "inspect element" and the code we get in soup object are different. There is still one more question. I got only 30 outputs from this code. The website auto loads the content when we scroll down. The code should be able to scroll down and get the other details.

Comment: You will get only the first 30 videos with this page. Not all videos in the creator channel.